# How to convert this non uniform XML file to a Pandas data frame

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I have an XML file like this

```xml
<TestingValue>

<result>

<attr1>Attribute1</attr1>
<attr2>Attribute2</attr2>

<feature>

<a>a2</a>
<b>b2</b>
<c>c2</c>
<d>d3</d>

</feature>
<feature>

<a>a1</a>
<b>b2</b>
<d>d3</d>


</feature>
<feature>
<b>b2</b>
<c>c2</c>
<d>d3</d>

</feature>
<feature>
<a>a1</a>
<b>b2</b>



</feature>

<feature>
<a>a1</a>

<d>d3</d>

</feature>


</result>

</TestingValue>
```

I need to create a pandas data frame like this.

```
     Attr1         Attr2      a    b   c   d
Attribute 1   Attribute2      a2   b2  c2  d2
Attribute 1   Attribute2      a1   b2  00  d3
Attribute 1   Attribute2      00   b2  c2  d3
Attribute 1   Attribute2      a1   b2  00  00
Attribute 1   Attribute2      a1   00  00  d3
```

To add to the problem, I do not know how many features tags or elements are in there inside result tag.

I need to find which values are not present and pad them with zeros. I have not been able to do that yet. How do I find out the format of the pandas dataframe then find out which elements do not have a specific feature tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the trick.

```
import pandas as pd                                                                                 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et                                                                  

def xml_to_df(filename):                                                                            
    rows = []                                                                                       
    attributes = {}                                                                                 
    xtree = et.parse("data.xml")                                                                    
    xroot = xtree.getroot()                                                                         
    result = xroot.find("result")                                                                   
    for feature_or_attr in result:                                                                  
        if feature_or_attr.tag == "feature":                                                        
            rows.append({node.tag: node.text for node in feature_or_attr})                          
        else:                                                                                       
            attributes[feature_or_attr.tag] = feature_or_attr.text                                  
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows)                                                                         
    df.fillna('00', inplace=True)                                                                   
    for key, val in attributes.items():                                                             
        df[key] = val                                                                               
    return df                                                                                       

print(xml_to_df("data.xml"))
```

Output:

```
    a   b   c   d       attr1       attr2
0  a2  b2  c2  d3  Attribute1  Attribute2
1  a1  b2  00  d3  Attribute1  Attribute2
2  00  b2  c2  d3  Attribute1  Attribute2
3  a1  b2  00  00  Attribute1  Attribute2
4  a1  00  00  d3  Attribute1  Attribute2
```

To address your point about not knowing which values are null -- pandas does not care. As I construct each `row`, I am only defining as many features as are available. When each `row` object becomes an actual row in the `DataFrame`, pandas automatically fills missing values with NaN. Those are all replaced with `df.fillna('00', inplace=True)`.

The names of the columns are generated based on the values in the XML.

Comment: How would this code change if there are many result elements in the same file with the same structure?

Comment: @BountyCollector You would change `result = root.find("result")` to `for result in root.findall("result"):` , then put the for-loop over `feature_or_attr` inside of that loop.